# Can i use foreach when i import all components in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

i'm trying to use **foreach** when **importing all** the components(images), from a location where i have an **index.js**, but looks like doesn't work.

I only can access to images in this way:

```
import * as AllPics from '../assets/images'
.
.
.
<img src={AllPics.Image1} />
<img src={AllPics.Image2} />
```

I wish to do something like this:

```
import * as AllPics from '../assets/images'
.
.
.
{ AllPics.foreach((image) => <img src={image} /> )
```

Do you know if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

`AllPics` is a namespace, which is an object (though a special kind of one). You can iterate over its values with `Object.values`:

```
{Object.values(AllPics).map(
  image => <img src={image} />
)}
```